# Why I have interactions from other countries if I have only selected one country (Colombia) to my Action on Google to be available?

Tags: google-analytics, actions-on-google

I developed an Action to deliver a response to a questions, when I configure the information related with the Deploy release, I selected Location targeting only to Colombia.

[Location Targeting Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1WEC.png)

The version was approved and passed the certification process, however when I reviewed the Analytics data I notice on the usage tab that other countries are reporting information like a unique users (e. g. Argentina, Mexico, Spain, others)

[Unique users Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig1d1.png)

[CSV Export Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnVG5.png)

According to the Location targeting configuration, it should only have information from Colombia, however I am receiving information from other countries, is this normal behavior or is it an analytics error?

Comment: What locales do you have enabled for your Action?

Comment: Hello @NickFelker I only enable to Colombia not in another locate [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1WEC.png)